# GraphQLHttpFailureDomain - Facebook Login on real device

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm having serios issues with facebook log in using a real device. I'm getting this error

```
-10-29 15:23:28.622 21689-21689/apps.vanilla.edvin.myapplication W/System.err: CONNECTION_FAILURE: TigonError(3): GraphQLHttpFailureDomain(401) HTTP Error
at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:219)
at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:174)
at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:92)
at com.vanillapps.caietvirtual.Start.Autentication.LoginFragment.onActivityResult(LoginFragment.java:269)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:160)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7289)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4516)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4563)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1698)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Using the emulator, login works without issues.

Any suggestions regarding my issue? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't say "u no haz internet", it says that the response was a (401) HTTP Error.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thanks. I was thinking about another issue when I wrote this. Any suggestions on how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? Facing same problem here.